How to identify code convention issues in PHP like ESLint + Prettier
I'm working on a PHP project and I'm looking for a way to identify and fix code convention issues. I'm familiar with ESLint and Prettier for JavaScript, and I'm wondering if there are similar tools available for PHP.
I'm particularly interested in tools that can check for things like:

Consistent indentation
Proper use of whitespace
Naming conventions
Consistent use of braces
....

I've searched for PHP code convention tools, but I haven't been able to find anything that seems as comprehensive as ESLint + Prettier. I've tried using PHP CodeSniffer, but it doesn't seem to be as user-friendly or as customizable as ESLint.
I'm hoping to find a tool that can help me to automatically identify and fix code convention issues in my PHP code. This would save me a lot of time and effort, and it would help to ensure that my code is consistent and easy to read.
Additional details:

I'm using PHP 8.2.
I'm using PhpStorm(paid version) as my editor.


If you find PHP CodeSniffer hard to configure, you could try combining it with PHPCS Fixer. Firstly start fixer then analyse code with code sniffer:
// I'm using Symfony 6.4 framework and squizlabs/php_codesniffer, friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer packages
php vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix src/
php vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR12 -s --colors --extensions=php src

and fixer config is quite easy to understand:
$finder = (new PhpCsFixer\Finder())
    ->in(__DIR__)
    ->exclude('var')
;

return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    ->setRules([
        '@Symfony' => true,
        'concat_space' => false,
        'phpdoc_var_without_name' => false,
        'single_line_after_imports' => true,
        'class_definition' => false,
        'single_line_throw' => false,
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder)
;

https://cs.symfony.com/doc/config.html
You could also try setting up PHPStan (I think it is the most popular), Psalm and Mess Detector all configurable from you PHPStorm settings (PHP/Quality Tools)
